# Why is my "Synchronize with Google" option grayed out in Mountain Lion Contacts?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, contacts, google

I have been syncing Mac OS contacts (Address Book) with Google for a long time. For some reason, though, that option is now grayed out in Contacts preferences.

Why? How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because you have Contact syncing via iCloud turned on. You can turn this off using the check-box in Preferences > iCloud.

I don't have iCloud syncing for Contacts and *can* sync via Google, but when I turn iCloud syncing on it warns me that Google syncing will be turned off...